# TYPO3 DataHandler: Copying record and relate it to itself --> running into loop

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm developing an event extension with recurring dates. Therefor, I have a recurring date pattern and copy the record for each date. So the record has a relation to itself:
- Main Event
-- N Child Events

Currently, I use the DataHandler method copyRecord, which works perfect. But this just copies the record, without mapping the relation.
- Main Event --> should have the count of children in the database
-- N Child Events --> should habe the relation to its parent main event

The DB should look like:
Event 1 (Main Event) | uid: 1 | event: 0 | recurring_children: 3 (count)
Event copy 1 | uid: 2 |  event: 1 | recurring_children: 0
Event copy 2 | uid: 3 |  event: 1 | recurring_children: 0
Event copy 3 | uid: 4 |  event: 1 | recurring_children: 0

I tried several ways, but none without problems.

The following try sets the relation in the database, but creates more events (I guess, this loops and I have to build a condition to avoid filling the datamap with duplications):

```
    public function processDatamap_afterDatabaseOperations(
    $status,
    $table,
    $recordUid,
    array $fields,
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $parentObject){

    $event = BackendUtility::getRecord($table, $recordUid);
    if ($status === 'update') {
        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $tce */
        $tce = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler::class);
        $tce->start(array(), array());
        $overrides = [
            'is_recurring_parent' => 0,
            'is_recurring_child' => 1,
            'recurring_weekdays' => '',
            'recurring_period_end' => '0000-00-00',
            'event' => $recordUid,
            'title' => 'FOOBAR'
        ];

        if ($event['is_recurring_parent']) {
            $foobar = $tce->copyRecord('tx_technoseumevents_domain_model_event', $event['uid'], $event['pid'], false, $overrides);
        }
```

T3 version 8.7

Sorry, my first time I'm using the datahandler for complex tasks. Maybe someone has a hint for me...

Answer (score 1):

The recursiveness happening in the first place, indicates a problem with your architecture that might be worth addressing before this problem as it would solve it at the root cause instead of treating symptoms. Normally, a record should not relate to itself - but that said, recursiveness can happen in other ways and it might not be possible to avoid in your use case.

Advise for addressing the problem:

- Consider adding a condition that prevents your code from being called on tables other than the one table you need to operate on. This alone could actually be why your copies recurse so that's number one to handle.
- If possible, and if you are not concerned with short-circuiting things like changing the title TCA field for a record to prepend "Copy of", or causing the copy to be hidden, you can switch to `copyRecord_raw`. It takes slightly different arguments (you may have to refactor to pass some arguments as part of the overrides array, compared to calling `copyRecord`). Doing that will prevent hooks from being called on the children you copy.
- You are using a nested DataHandler instance - it might be preferable to call that method on the `$dataHandler` instance in your example. The DataHandler maintains a copy stack, but (parts of) it will only work if you do things in the same instance and only for some particular hooks (i.e. the pre-type and not-global hooks).
- Lastly, there exists a runtime cache entry which contains an array of records which have been copied. Although the utility methods that access and store entries in this cache entry are not publicly accessible - so you cannot call them from your hook class - you can read the array of entries, manipulate it and put it back to prevent recursive processing of the same record. See the method isNestedElementCallRegistered in DataHandler (https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/v8.7.17/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php#L9034).

Final note: the after-database-operations hook may be called at times when you do not expect it. For example, if you copy a record and also move it (as in: the copy comes from the UI, not programmatically) the array you receive in `$fieldArray` may not be the final one (for example, `pid` may be an unexpected value). Not being aware of this and the peculiarities above might also increase the danger of unintentionally causing recursive operations.

EDIT: If you are using bi-directional relations in TCA then removing one side may also improve the situation. For example, each "date" doesn't necessarily have to be aware of which event it is associated with. Something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @claus-due. 
Sometimes, two steps back are better then one more into the wrong direction. I was already thinking about the relation to itself, so I decided to add another data layer which holds the relation between the events, which makes it a lot easier to handle. Event > RecurringProfile, where RecurringProfile holds the ID of the parent event and all relations to its created children.
I post my result as soon as I'm done with it.